# How to debug app on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

I am a Windows guy, and I have just developed an ionic hybrid app on Android. During the development, I can easily inspect & debug my app using Google Chrome and run `chrome://inspect`.

Due to the need to deploy app on iOS, I have to use Mac. Am I able to do all those thing above on Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can debug both iOS and Android apps on a Mac. While on Android you can still use Chrome, for iOS Safari has built in support for debugging  web views.

First enable the developer menu in Safari. You can find this in Preferences -> Advanced. Then while you have a connected device or simulator running your app, open the Develop menu, select your device and then select your app to open the dev tools.

If you are more comfortable with Chrome's tools you may want to look at [this project](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy). Not all of the dev tools features are supported though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Now, I am able to debug app running in simulator from Safari. However, I can't see my device in the menu list. Therefore, I can't debug app running on the device. What do I need to do to debug app running on device?

Comment: Sometimes removing and plugging the device back in helps. Or quiting and restarting safari